# Is there any possible way that hybrids can mate?

Tags: zoology

I'm writing a book, and a a portion of it involves a society of humanzees. Now, is there any *plausible* way that a hybrid (such as a humanzee) could procreate either with one another, or with their father/mother species? I apologize for my lack of understanding of biology, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is a hypothetical scenario which I think could be compared in parallel to hybrids like a mule (offspring of a male donkey and a female horse) or a hinny (offspring of a male horse and a female donkey) or zebroids ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebroid)). In the case of the fertility of mules on wikipedia it is stated that

> A few female mules have produced offspring when mated with a purebred
>   horse or donkey.

with examples being given as

> Since 1527 there have been more than 60 documented cases of foals born
>   to female mules around the world. There are reports that a mule in
>   China produced a foal in 1984. In Morocco, in early 2002, a mare mule
>   produced a rare foal. In 2007 a mule named Kate gave birth to a mule
>   son in Colorado. Blood and hair samples were tested verifying that the
>   mother was a mule and the colt was indeed her offspring ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule#Fertility)).

In the case of a hinny fertility is much more rare but there is a documented case on Wikipedia

> In China in 1981, a hinny mare proved fertile with a donkey stallion.
>   When the Chinese hinny was bred to a donkey jack, she produced "Dragon
>   Foal," who resembled a donkey with mule-like features ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinny#Fertility.2C_sterility.2C_and_rarity)).

The [wikipedia page on hybrids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_%28biology%29) will also be of interest in your research. In short, hybrids can procreate and give birth in rare cases. However, I wouldn't vouch on the survivability of the offsprings. Since your work is fictional, it is entirely left to your discretion on that topic. Btw, humazee or humzee makes a more intriguing name maybe. Good luck with the book.

Answer (score 1):

Recent genetic analysis of human DNA shows [neanderthal ancestry](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/37/15129), so inter-species breeding to produce reproductively viable offspring (humanderthals?) appears to be possible - at least between species of the same genus. But with *Homo sapiens* being the only extant species in the genus *Homo* you'd be really stretching the boundaries of plausibility to have a human/ape or human/monkey hybrid.